# Fluentd is adding multiple same records

Tags: fluentd

Request your help.

We are using AKS Cluster and want to ingest custom application logs in elastic search. All the setup for Fluentd deployment , Elastic Search and Kibana is completed on aks and is working. We have mounted azure file share in the pod and have application has started putting custom application logs. Below is the configuration of Fluentd file. Now the problem is for each log we are getting records multipled by nodes. For example if a AKS cluster has 10 nodes then same log is ingested 10 times into elastic search and 10 times it is shown in Kibana.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-config
  namespace: efk-cloud
data:
  fluent.conf: |-
    @include kubernetes.conf
    #@include file.conf
    #Just an example of what kind of variables can come inside. This part does not apply as config. Do your config with ENV vars
    <match **>
      @type elasticsearch
      @id out_es
      @log_level info
      include_tag_key true
      host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
      port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
      user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER']}"
      scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'https'}"
      password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD']}"
      index_name efk-cloud-02
      type_name fluentd
    </match>
  kubernetes.conf: |-
    <match fluent.**>
      @type null
    </match>
    <source>
      @type tail
      @id in_tail_containers_logs
      path /var/log/customlog/*.log
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
      tag kubernetes.*
      read_from_head true
      format json
      time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
    </source>
```

Answer (score 0):

@hitesh-nayyar It sounds like you have fluentd/fluentbit deployed as a daemonset, each node daemon running the same config, and have your application writing to an Azure file share which is also mounted to each AKS node.

1. You applicaion writes a log line to the log file on the file share
2. This file share is mounted to each node so it is read and processed
   by each fluentd/fluentbit daemon independently
3. ES/Kibana show 10 log lines, one for each node that processed the file

To mitigate this, you should only have one point of ingestion for these logs. There are many ways to accomplish this but this is what I would first try:

1. Configure App to log to AKS node storage rather than file share
2. Re-configure fluent to read/process App log from node storage

*Note: you'll want the fluent position file (`pos_file`) to persist through a restart to avoid re-processing from the head if fluent gets killed, restarts, or dies.*